# Mongo Connector doesn't sync properly

Tags: mongodb, connector

Here's my problem.

Our solution :

Front web connect to a cloud mongodb instances.

End-point client connect to a local mongodb instances.

People put some data throught the Front web, those data must be sync to the local instances for end-point client.

End-point client generate some data to the local's instance which must be sync to the cloud environnement.

================================

I tried to use mongo-connector to sync both way and I did sync something but everytime mongo-connector sync only half of the data randomely...

Here's my local mongodb conf :

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /server/mongo/data
  journal:
    enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

replication:
  replSetName: rs-local
```

Master mongodb conf:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /server/mongo/data
  journal:
    enabled: true


# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo


#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: master-replica-01
```

This is the command I use for mongo-connector :

```
/usr/local/bin/mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t X.X.X.X:27017 -d mongo_doc_manager -n "db.role,db.site,db.split,db.organism,db.users,db.namespace1.namespace2.namespace3.*" --admin-username mongosu --password verysecretpassword--oplog-ts /server/mongo/data/oplog.timestamp --no-dump --enable-syslog
```

Everytime I dump the database then launch the mongo-connector I got some of my data but not all of it...

I thought it was an oplog problem so set the oplog to 16Gb.

Many help ask :)

Elenui

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I'm having the same problem.